# Is it possible to extend the time i'm logged as administrator when enter sudo mode from the console?

Tags: sudo

Is it possible to extend the time i'm logged as administrator when enter sudo mode from the console?
If yes, how?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the terminal type this to open a file to edit:

```
sudo visudo
```

Find this:

```
Defaults        env_reset
```

And replace with this:

```
Defaults        env_reset,timestamp_timeout=NUMBER
```

Where `NUMBER` is the number of minutes to time-out.

Then save the file.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, it is possible.

Edit the sudoers file by typing the following at the command prompt:

```
sudo visudo
```

Find the section commented with `# Defaults specification` and look for a line like this:

```
Defaults  env_reset
```

Change that line to:

```
Defaults  env_reset,timestamp_timeout=10
```

Where you can replace `10` with whatever the number of minutes you'd like for the sudo password to live. Save the changes and you're done.

Edit: if you don't like to use `vi` you can tell `visudo` to use another editor. The editor must block until you're done with your edits. Just set the `EDITOR` environment variable before envoking `visudo` and it will use that editor instead:

```
EDITOR=/usr/bin/nano sudo visudo
```

would use `nano` to edit the file instead. I recommend you *do not* use a graphical editor like Sublime Text without knowing how to run the editor, from the command line, in blocking mode (for `subl` that means calling it with `--wait`).

Comment: How would I do it in nano rather than vi / vim?

Comment: sudo nano /etc/sudoers

Comment: @codecowboy that's not a good way to do it. `visudo` just doesn't edit the `/etc/sudoers` file directly. It edits a copy of the file and, when you save it, it verifies that copy is syntactically correct before it replaces `/etc/sudoers` with the copy. This is very important. It's super is easy to screw that file up and bork your system. See above for how you use another editor if `vi` isn't your thing.

Comment: Interestingly enough, `visudo` takes the editor from `$EDITOR` if defined while `sudo -e` (which can be used to edit any file) first looks at `$SUDO_EDITOR`.

Answer (score -4):

`sudo bash`

You may now remain the root user for as long as you want. No tinkering with system files required.

`exit` or `<control-d>` to return to the normal universe.

Comment: I don't think this is a good idea to keep remaining as root user. since this doesn't need sudo at all, it's more dangerous.

Comment: This is not the answer to the question, but I'd argue, that if you have a lot to do as a root it's much more feasible to actually log in as one. Tho I preffer to do 'sudo su -', or just du sudo passwd, create password for root, and then just use 'su -' to switch to root... Anyway, that's outside of the scope of the question.

Comment: @nelson explain the difference between getting a root shell and prefixing every command with `sudo`

Comment: @MarekBettman it exactly answers the question. Q: "How do I extend the time..." A: "sudo bash -> infinite time"

Comment: I may not want to give blanket root shell access to someone. In this case, extending the time to live on cached sudo credentials is markedly different from just getting a shell with elevated privileges. It is also considered exceptionally bad system administration hygiene to elevate a shell like this. Typing an additional word to run a command with elevated privledges keeps you conscious of the seriousness of the act and the damage that can ensue if you're not careful.